# How to add aurioTouch files to custom program?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

I'm trying to integrate the aurioTouch Apple sample in my app. I have put all the code that was in aurioTouch. When I import FFTBufferManager to my custom class it show error:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's always best to provide a MWE where this error occurs - provide us with as **little** of your code as possible so we can help you find the error. But first you should mention what you have tried so far!

Comment: @TobiasKienzler i have changed file ext to .hh .mm .hpp (as i follow from stack question ) .. in my case simply i added given files in auriotouch to my program and in my customClass( say record view controller.h) i wrote #import "EAGLView.h"
#import "FFTBufferManager.h"(which wAS IN audio touch program) when i wrote  last line in my sample program it show error as shown in above pic .@TobiasKienzler did you have auriotouch program ,if don't have i can send to solve my problem

Comment: @wss Sorry, I don't even know objective-c let alone auriotouch, just trying to help you improve your question - you can always edit it. It's much better to post source code directly (but not too much!) since nobody is willing to re-type it from a screenshot. That also helps so others can google for it. And since you mention another question, you should include a link here. Btw. [here](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)'s an excellent guide how increase the likelyhood of answers

Comment: As I mentioned I don't know objective-c, but since the error reads "did you mean Class?" did you try it with a capital 'C' instead?

Comment: thks for giving a time,, yes i tried with Capital c.. but that w'll be different concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is given in following steps.

1. Open your project and import all classes from aurioTouch(inculde aurioTouchAppDelegate class)
2. This step is somewhat tricky .. open your class xib ..is this drag object from object library and put class of object to aurioTouchAppDelegate class
3. In your xib, drag view  and put its class to eaglview ... know once again click on object in its connection tab .. you will see view and window .. if you see that means you are going in right direction .. make connection of your view with that
4. Make outlet of OBJECT in your custom class ... ...run your project it will show graph in your custom class.